# string.split parse url from large string

Tags: c#, string, parsing, text, split

How would I parse and extract the url from this large string of text in the image below?

I want the *.m3u8* link.
I tried using `String.split()` but that only accepts chars and not strings.

[image]

Comment: Firstly, post the text not an image, its annoying. Secondly you really need to explain what actually constitutes as the url, i.e where does it stop, because its not clear from that ghastly image

Comment: is your qeustion 'can't use string.Split("")' ?

Comment: There exits an overload that accepts an array of string separators: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this approach would be right but I guess you can remove those lines containing "EXT" if they are common in your url.

```
var result = url.Split(new [] { '\r', '\n' }); // converting string to lines
for (int i=0;i<=result.Length-1;i++) // Finding if EXT text is present and removing them
  {
    if (result[i].Contains("EXT-")
      result.RemoveAt(i);
  }
string final = string.Join("", result); // converting back to string
```

Tell me if it works for you!

Answer (score -2):

> How would I parse and extract the url from this large string of text?

use this code:

```
void Main()
{
    var text = @"
otEXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID=720p30',NAME=*720p°,AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YESEXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2374703,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS=•avc1.77.31,mp4a.40.2',VIDEO=720p30'
http://video-weaver.lax03.hls.tbmw.net/v1/playlist/CuoCf3YooUjSfbk71Zs3ig68T2vDVg7449mAN78mSV1oQ9V7skuTh6NP9FOSaIgGNgnpliscdDC9XvjGyGcYrIXBbAXSkqCGuIOTQgtIw5IQLUIbHGMZIXWZeD6Urd4GzyPxCoARIYyo6i5ECCfK2r1jW1kidXGotcRXy6fHolJw-rC9xPPYc2IxYKaERQ9NsOMGn3m2ChqWFSpRHbYNK1M8OrU4WecMwgoFkORbEBEmAmng2V8GnGz63hWNV2sDW1H9E5pYjG4jpPLEf_Fwt75CePIgyZ9g30Kgr5CHZYSyMMbMAX-eac5wC3wjVUWtGz094t4xH1713yvWjv813vCY6NRBCPkCINdpXBmUnLcnE1JOLye_NiGx5R1B4IMDpRXDZQAO6PBm97ZNhyLZKc9Awg5vypphWG2MMAGdboca5WGtG_wVRp12SiHw9n0a51VpqNjVVVWbASuUly-CEe22tzLkwEolOWGE8VQSECyPx17qBU7YPHCEEi8ncnMaDly1Dn8j0xU-QN71kA.m3u8  
    ";

    MatchCollection ms = Regex.Matches(text, @"(www.+|http.+)([\s]|$)");
    string url = ms[0].Value.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(url);
}
```

[image]

---

> I tried using String.Split but that only accepts chars and not strings.

this question you can use extension
but it's can't deal your problem

```
void Main()
{
    var extention_str = "http://aaacccddd".Split("ccc");
}

public static class StrinExtention {
    public static string [] Split(this string str,string separator){
        return str.Split(new string [] {separator},StringSplitOptions.None);
    }
}
```

[image]